# Where is the VGG in Cartoongan?

Tags: gan

When I read through the paper of Cartoongan [CartoonGAN: Generative Adversarial Networks for Photo Cartoonization], I was so confused about where is vgg located in the entire network.

Based on the paper about GAN [Generative Adversarial Nets], I could not see anywhere that vgg exists in the network.

I feel that I couldn't see a clear picture of the entire construction of Cartoongan. I know how GAN is constructed with a generator and discriminator, but Cartoongan no. If someone can help, I appreciated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question, VGG is mostly used as feature extraction. As such we can compare the similarity between the styles of the two images. Usually ground truth batch of images and the ones that are generated.

This is mainly used as an extra term in the loss function. As shown below `s_loss` and `c_loss`

This can be seen on the [GitHub repo of the paper in question](https://github.com/mnicnc404/CartoonGan-tensorflow/blob/2f26a525f8b604b8e98fb84ebad0af5aef727944/train.py#L292):

```py
if self.content_lambda != 0. or self.style_lambda != 0.:
    vgg_generated_images = self.pass_to_vgg(generated_images)
    if self.content_lambda != 0.:
        c_loss = self.content_lambda * self.content_loss(
            self.pass_to_vgg(source_images), vgg_generated_images)
        g_total_loss = g_total_loss + c_loss
    if self.style_lambda != 0.:
        s_loss = self.style_lambda * self.style_loss(
            self.pass_to_vgg(target_images[:vgg_generated_images.shape[0]]),
            vgg_generated_images)
        g_total_loss = g_total_loss + s_loss

d_grads = d_tape.gradient(d_total_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)
g_grads = g_tape.gradient(g_total_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
```

Where the VGG is initialized and loaded at the begging of training, [as shown below](https://github.com/mnicnc404/CartoonGan-tensorflow/blob/2f26a525f8b604b8e98fb84ebad0af5aef727944/train.py#L115):

```py
base_model = VGG19(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)
tmp_vgg_output = base_model.get_layer("block4_conv3").output
tmp_vgg_output = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='linear', padding='same',
                        name='block4_conv4')(tmp_vgg_output)
self.vgg = tf.keras.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=tmp_vgg_output)
self.vgg.load_weights(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(
    "~", ".keras", "models",
    "vgg19_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5")), by_name=True)
```